# Unable to retrieve entity resolution from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Good afternoon.

I've trained a LUIS app to recognize specific names from a list of synonyms (Entity type: List).
For example, the normalized value for `["ada", "aDa", "lovelace"]` is `"Ada Lovelace"`.

I'm using the [Enterprisebot demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBotServices-scenarios/tree/master/CSharp/Enterprise/src/Enterprisebot) as a starting point to my app, and it works like a charm. Problem is, I can't retrieve the normalized value (aka. one of its Resolution) from my query.

The API is doing fine. The problem is that the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis package puts the resolutions inside a `IDictionary < string, object >` structure.

For example, the API correctly identifies the following entity:

```
"entities": [
        {
            "entity": "lovelace",
            "type": "Sala",
            "startIndex": 16,
            "endIndex": 23,
            "resolution": {
                "values": [
                    "Ada Lovelace"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

But when I try to access its resolution, I can't read the Value field from the IDictionary pair.

```
Console.Write( enttt.Entity );

    // "lovelace"

Console.Write( enttt.Type );

    // "Sala"

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution );

    // System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution.First() );

    // [values, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]]

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution.First().Key );

    // "values"

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution.First().Value );

    // System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution.First().Value.toString() );

    // System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

Console.Write( enttt.Resolution.First().Value.First() );

    // object does not contain a definition for 'First'
```

I've tried `enttt.Resolution.Values.First()` as well, but to the same result.

How do I access the first "value", so I can retrieve the normalized value `"Ada Lovelace"`?
There is no `string IDictionary.Get(string key)` method as far as I could tell, or is there?

Comment: Can't you just cast it to a `Dictionary<>`, or instantiate a new `Dictionary<>` and set it equal to your `IDictionary<>` you are using?

Comment: @JasonSowers Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
var normalizedValue = result.Entities[0].Resolution.Values.Select(s => ((List<object>)s)[0]).FirstOrDefault();
```